# TclError: couldn't connect to display "localhost:11.0"

Tags: python, tkinter, jupyter

I am setting my Jupyter notebook in my service computer which is in cloud. The system is Ubuntu 20.04. Everything is ok when I run my code. But when I use the tkinter ,there is a problem as below:

```
TclError: couldn't connect to display "localhost:11.0".
```

And here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
window= Tk()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `tkinter` requires a display to run

Comment: Seems like you are using SSH with X-forwarding to connect the service computer in cloud, then you need to run a X11 server in your local computer.